# Why does the STL/Boost C++ coding style differ so much from everyone elses?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm a fairly rookie C++ programmer, but in my limited experience with the language, most standard C++ style guidelines (e.g. [Google C++ Style Guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)) go against what is implemented in the stl and boost libraries.

For example, class names in the C++ standard library and Boost are always lower case, with underscores separating words (e.g. `std::vector`, `boost::unordered_map`, `std::map::const_iterator`), whereas most style guides I've seen for C++ tend towards a CamelCase style (e.g. `TcpConnection` or `Int32`).

The same applies to methods too. The standard library and Boost use the same style for methods and functions as they do for classes (e.g. `std::map<>::get_equal("foo")`), whereas most style guides advocate pascalCase or CamelCase.

If we contrast this with a language like Ruby, where most users will adhere to the conventions used in the core libraries, it seems odd that there'd be such a difference between the standard C++ libraries and everyone else's code.

**Does anyone know why this is?**

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm talking simply about the superficial textual style (casing, use of underscores, etc) rather than actual implementation style.

Comment: My personal impression is that most people who write style guides do so out of fear of C++. The Google style guide is full of arguments like "don't do this because people who don't understand C++ may not understand this". Then they saw Java coming along as an "understandable OO language" and said, "hey, that's a neat style, let's write like that and it's less scary". That's just my opinion, of course. (Me, I find the standard library style much less noisy and visually tiring.)

Comment: Boost is being designed with compatibility with the STL in mind: a number of classes that started in Boost have been integrated nearly "as-is" in the STL with C++11 for example, and there is more to come. There are also a fair number of the C++ comittee members working on Boost... So I guess that Boost is *naturally* aligned with the STL.

Comment: Just to be clear. are you solely talking about "superficial" stuff like naming conventions, or also more fundamental stuff, like (mostly) avoiding virtual functions and inheritance, and free functions instead of class members where possible?

Comment: I guess it's because C++ programmers are generally hard-core, no-holds-barred, kick-ass developers who laugh at the standards and go off and do stuff their own way because they can and-who-are-you-to-argue-with-me!

Comment: @jalf - Yeah I just mean the superficial use of underscores and letter casing.

Comment: underscores and lowercase was the style perferred by Bjarne Strustrep in "The C++ Programming Language". If I recall correctly he had made a statement along the lines that underscores in names were to be preferred because it was more readable to an international community where english is not the primary language. I have no idea if his opinion is true or not, but I'm guessing that's the origin.

Comment: I don't know the answer. I tried writing out a big answer about how some people followed Microsoft's lead with PascalCase, and some probably tried to follow Java's style, and the C++ standard library followed C's style, but in the end, that doesn't really answer the question of *why* these divergent styles were all so widely adopted. So I guess I'll make it a comment instead. I guess unlike Ruby, C++ doesn't have a benevolent dictator at the top deciding on the One True Naming Convention. And early C++ APIs were often ported from other languages (Pascal or C), using their naming conventions

Comment: there's a lot to disagree with in the Google C++ Style Guidelines on the substantial level (eg. they proscribe exceptions, and the rationale boils down to "we don't want to use them because we don't use them".  yes, it's *that* circular).  on the superficial level, and beside the stuff Kerrek SB mentioned: it's just opinions, and those are like... hmmm, rectums.  everybody has one.  so what.

Comment: I've always blamed Microsoft's MFC stuff for espousing the ugly-as-sin style of pkSomeThingThatDoesWhoKnowsWhat. After working with MFC code I find the STL to be like a cold beer on a hot summer day :-)

Comment: The STL was around long before google, so I have no idea why their style guide would influence anything.

Comment: Surely this is a questions about the behavior of *programmers* not a *programming* question, and as such belongs on Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

underscores and lowercase was the style perferred by Bjarne Stroustrup in "The C++ Programming Language". If I recall correctly he had made a statement along the lines that underscores in names were to be preferred because it was more readable to an international community where english is not the primary language. I have no idea if his opinion is true or not, but I'm guessing that's the origin.

Here's a link to his FAQ where he discusses this very topic:

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#Hungarian

Snippet explaining what you were interested in in particular:

> I prefer to use underscores to separate words in an identifier (e.g, element_count) rather than alternatives, such as elementCount and ElementCount. Never use names with all capital letter (e.g., BEGIN_TRANSACTION) because that's conventionally reserved for macros. Even if you don't use macros, someone might have littered your header files with them. Use an initial capital letter for types (e.g., Square and Graph). ***The C++ language and standard library don't use capital letters, so it's int rather than Int and string rather than String. That way, you can recognize the standard types.***

Answer (score 8):

There is a good reason beside Bjarne Stroustrup one. When using functors you want them to look like a functions.

But with CamelCase style guides you distinguish Classes from Methods and Functions by using Capitals on the first char of Classes name and LowerCase on the first char of a method.

This is not consistent with c++ algorithm style programming. As there is no reason to distinguish a functor from a function, it's preferable to use c++ and stl coding styles when you want to use functors (and usually you want).

Answer (score 5):

The only rules that truly are needed are those designed to prevent known problems:

- Use ALL_CAPS (plus underscores and digits) for preprocessor names, and only for preprocessor names. It can be tough chasing down problems caused by collisions between a (supposedly) non-preprocessor identifier and a preprocessor name, tougher yet to fix them.
- Never start an identifier with an underscore, and don't have a double underscore anywhere inside an identifier. Those are reserved for the implementation.

Beyond this, be consistent, and don't be too picky. Coding standards should be mindful of rule #0, which is "Don't sweat the small stuff." Far too many coding standards sweat the small stuff.

As far as Google's C++ standard goes, it's not the best. It's more of a C plus or minus standard. It prohibits pass by non-constant reference, for example.